# Router is undefined inside highcharts

Tags: angular, routes

I have to send the parameters shown below to another component by routing:

[image: code snippet]

The word in square brackets is the alt text, which gets displayed if the browser can't show the image. Be sure to include meaningful alt text for screen-reading software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal scope problem in JS .

you can do something like this i.e use `ES6` fat arrow function : `() => {}`

`click : (eve) => {
 this.router.navigate([]) //will work as () => {} preserve the scope
}`

Comment: How do I get the series name?

Comment: @rharrison33 i did not understand your question

Comment: Before I used this method, I could get the series name by this.series.name, but using this method I don't have access to this.series.

Comment: Also, I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a variable which value is "this" before going in highcharts settings, because "this" refers to highcharts object, and using it rather than "this" to call router.
`const _this = this;
...
{
...
    _this.router.navigate.....
...
}`

Comment: I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined.